# Update SQL Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I need to update the database with a request from ajax, only when I write this code, I do not update the database

```
  global $wpdb;

    if ( isset( $_POST['edit_row'] ) ){
    $wpdb->update( 'wp_rel_eq', array(
        'id'=>$_POST['row_id'],
        'title' => $_POST['title_val'], 
        'anonce' => $_POST['anonce_val'],
        'url' => $_POST['url_val'],),
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 
    );
     echo mysql_insert_id();
     exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation of wordpress

```
 <?php $wpdb->update( $table, $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null ); ?>
```

As per your code you missed third parameter which is  `$where`

**Examples**
Update a row, where the ID is 1, the value in the first column is a string and the value in the second column is a number:

```
$wpdb->update( 
    'table', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1',  // string
        'column2' => 'value2'   // integer (number) 
    ), 
    array( 'ID' => 1 ), 
    array( 
        '%s',   // value1
        '%d'    // value2
    ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
```

documentation Ref:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

if i split your code then

`$table` will be

```
 wp_rel_eq
```

`$data` will be

```
 array(
    'id'=>$_POST['row_id'],
    'title' => $_POST['title_val'], 
    'anonce' => $_POST['anonce_val'],
    'url' => $_POST['url_val'],)
```

`$where` not passed

```
$format  will be

array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
```